# Pop Up View in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a popover view (without a tab bar) that is popped over to a view controller with a tab bar. In the view controller with a tab bar I set up a button to click, so that the view controller pops up:

```
  @IBAction func PopUpClicked(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {

        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "SpinningWheel", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhotoPopUp") as! PopUpViewController

        self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)

        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
        popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

And in the popOver view controller, i animated the pop over.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)


        self.showAnimate()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


      func showAnimate()
        {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            self.view.alpha = 0.0;
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.view.alpha = 1.0
                self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)

            });
        }

        func removeAnimate()
        {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
                self.view.alpha = 0.0;

            }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
                if (finished)
                {
                    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            });
        }
```

But when the popover happens, Everything has a faded black background, which I want except for the tab bar. I would like for the pop over View to also pop over the tabbar and for the faded black background to go over it.

This is what I want it to look like: 
[image]

With the black faded background covering the tabbar

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/huynguyencong/EzPopup

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens, because you have to present your popover as a modal ViewController. To achieve this you have to set the modal presentation style before presenting your popover from your target ViewController. This code should be called in your presenting ViewController:

```
let vc = YourPopOverViewController(nib: UINib(name: "PopOverViewController", bundle: nil), bundle: nil)
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext

tabBarController.present(vc, animated: true)
```

EDIT:

This should do the trick if you have designed your `PopOverViewController` as a fullscreen ViewController. I have done this a bunch of times and have left the space which should not be presented as clear background:

```
@IBAction func PopUpClicked(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "SpinningWheel", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhotoPopUp") as! PopUpViewController
    popOverVc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
    tabBarController.present(popOverVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: `@IBAction func PopUpClicked(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
        
        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "SpinningWheel", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhotoPopUp") as! PopUpViewController
        self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
        popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        popOverVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overFullScreen
        
    }` I tried this and it doesn't work

Comment: You need as UIModalPresentationStyle OverCurrentContext

Comment: And you habe to present it over the UITabBarController. I haven't seen that you are using one

Comment: `popOverVc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext`  is this the part that is suppose to present it over the tabbarcontroller?

Comment: could I possibly make the view size really long as set the cliptoBounds = false. would that work?

Comment: You really need to have a whole UIViewController and you have to use the "present(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)" method. What you have done in your code snippet ist to add a subview but you need to present a viewController.

Answer (score 3):

This 3rd party EzPopup can resolve the problem easily: https://github.com/huynguyencong/EzPopup

```
// init YourViewController
let contentVC = ...

// Init popup view controller with content is your content view controller
let popupVC = PopupViewController(contentController: contentVC, popupWidth: 100, popupHeight: 200)

// show it by call present(_ , animated:) method from a current UIViewController
present(popupVC, animated: true)
```