# How to open pop up via code

Tags: swift, popup

I'm a very novice swift programmer who is trying to do the following: I have a simple game that generates a pop ups (via separate view controllers) by pressing certain buttons. I would also like to add some code (that runs after some event) that opens a popup under certain conditions. To this effect I have created a new view and view controller and linked them. In its entirety the view controller looks as follows:

```
import UIKit

class P2_Gift_Pop_Up: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("I was here")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }   
}
```

Now I try to call this view controller (to get the view to pop up) by using the following line in the code in the main viewcontroller:

`P2_Gift_Pop_Up()`

Swift accepts this yet when I run the app nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Calling `P2_Gift_Pop_Up()` does not present the viewController. Add the code to `MainViewController` so we can help you

Comment: The rest of the code in the MainViewController runs fine but is not relevant to what I'm trying to do here. Or maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: `P2_Gift_Pop_Up()` won't do the appropriate popping-up, checking this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44709096/pop-up-view-in-swift might be helpful to your case...

Comment: What do you mean when you say you have 'linked them'?  `P2_Gift_PopUp()` just creates a new instance of the view controller it does nothing to present or display it.

Comment: That I set the Class in the identity spector for the view to the view controller. But your comment clarified something for me anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    let button = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // setup button frame or constraint.. (unless done in IB)

        // add target to button (or add an IBOutlet from IB)

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = P2_Gift_Pop_Up()
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And inside `P2_Gift_Pop_Up` VC:

```
class P2_Gift_Pop_Up: UIViewController {

    let dismissButton = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // setup button frame or constraint
        // ..

        // add target to button

        dismissButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Calling `P2_Gift_Pop_Up()` in a viewController does not present it, in your case modal presentation works well because you want `P2_Gift_Pop_Up()` to pop up.

Comment: Thank you. Yes modal presentation would work well. But I dont want to do this by a button press. Does your answer pressupose this? Or does it just simulate a button? If so, is this necessary to get the desired effect.

Comment: You can call present and dismiss from anywhere doesn't have to be a button if thats what you meant. I just picked a button because its the most common and easier to show in an example

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't want to use a button I only used the following snippet in the main view controller.

```
let vc = P2_Gift_Pop_Up()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext 
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This starts running code in the popup window without any buttons, i.e. what I wanted.

However, when I run the following code

```
import UIKit

class P2_Gift_Pop_Up: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var Slot1: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    Slot1.setImage(UIImage(named: "Card 2 Red"), for: .normal)

  }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

}
```

I get the following error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What is wrong? The same code in popups that I opened with buttons in the main view controller works.

Ps. Sorry if posting this as an answer to my own question is the wrong way to go about this (commenting became unreadable when I included code, editing the original quesstion would have changed from what i origianally wanted to know, and I do answer what I originally wanted to know)

Comment: You have to add this as a new question no one can comment you the answer because as you said it becomes unreadable